# How to find a Parallel line for given A,B coordinates in 2D

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, svg, geometry

I have A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2) coordinates.I have the length and angle of the line.

I need to find the parallel line which gives me C(x3,y3) and D(x4,y4) coordinates at a particular distance.Its a slanted line.

Any pseudo code or math formula could help.

Ex: Given Coordinates 
**A(200,0) B(0,450). Angle of the line is 113.962 . Length of the line 492.4.**

Help me find C and D coordinates at distance 50 from A, B coordinates.

Please find image below, its a line with angle.

[image: Angular line]

[image: Updated Image for finding parallel line]

Comment: how is the distance measured ? is it along x-axis , y-axis or any other angle?

Comment: Just add 50 to the a.x and b.x. The resulting line will be parallel.

Comment: This is pretty basic geometry. Translate A and B by a vector V to get C and D. The length of V is your distance, and the angle of V is some angle that you haven't specified (along the x-axis is straightforward).

Comment: Its an angular line. Not a vertical or horizontal line.

Comment: Please find attached image @Nelfeal @ bhspencer @ SomeDude.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean that A is on the x axis and B is on the y axis, and so C should also be on the x axis and D on the y axis?

Comment: @Nelfeal - I have the angle please check along with the image.

Comment: Point C could be any point on a circle with radius 50 centered on point A; ditto for point D compared to point B, so technically there are an infinite number of solutions.   Translating 50 along the X axis, as several have suggested, would give you an answer that fits; so would translating along the Y axis, or any other direction.  I'm guessing what you actually mean to be asking is for a parallel line segment at distance 50 from the original line, *measured perpendicular to the original line* -- meaning ABCD would be a square. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Nelfeal @ Daniel...... I have attached an updated photo. Its in 2D and a polygon.

Comment: Well my first comment still stands. The angle of V is the angle of the line + or - 90°, depending on which side you want it. There are tons of resources online to learn how to translate a point by a vector.

Comment: OK, based on your updated image sounds like my guess was right (except for the "square" part which was my goofup -- that'd only work if the line segment is 50 units long.  ABCD would be a rectangle.)  You want to translate the line segment 50 units in a direction perpendicular to the line, not along the X or Y axis.

Comment: Perpendicular to the line @DanielBeck

Comment: @Nelfeal Geometry is a topic which I don't know and like much.Can you help me with a link plz.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your line has base point `(x1,y1)` and direction vector:

```
(dx, dy) = (x2-x1, y2-y1)
```

Normalize this vector dividing components by vector length:

```
len = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
(udx, udy) = (dx / len, dy / len)
```

perpendicular vector:

```
(px, py) = (-udy, udx)  
(note also reverse vector (udy, -udx) to shift onto another side)
```

Base point for parallel line at distance dist:

```
(nx, ny) = (x1 -udy * dist, y1 + udx * dist)
```

Second point, if you need:

```
(sx, sy) = (nx + dx, ny + dy)
```

Comment: Can we find with any cos and sin angles formula

Comment: can you explain me more. New to this vectors.

Comment: udx, udy are really cos and sin of the line inclination angle, but you don't need to use them explicitly. All formulas are done.

Comment: x1 = x + cos(ang) * distance;
y1 = y + sin(ang) * distance;

Comment: Having two points you don't need angles. Also note - perpendicular has **exchanged**  components, one is negated.

Comment: When these parallel lines intersect with a straight line , they go outside the outline and look weird.Please see updated image @MBo